# mongo-cxx-driver can not iterate view

Tags: mongo-cxx-driver

I have a mongodb collection with the following document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c879a2f277d8132d6707792"),
    "a" : "133",
    "b" : "daisy",
    "c" : "abc"
}
```

When I run the following mongocxx code:

```
auto r = client["DB"]["Collection"].find_one({}).value().view();
isREmpty = r.empty();
rLength = r.length();
isOneInR = r.begin() == r.end();

for (bsoncxx::document::element ele : r) {
    std::cout << "Got key" << std::endl;
}
```

I get isREmpty = false, rLength = 99, isOneInR = true and **no** output saying Got key.

I was expecting the print of "Got key" because one document returned from find_one.
Why isn't it showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are viewing freed memory. The call to `.value()` creates a temporary `bsoncxx::value` object. You then get a view into that temporary object with `.view()` and attempt to examine the data, but it is too late.

What you want to do instead is capture the cursor returned by `find_one`:

```
auto cursor = client["DB"]["Collection"].find_one({});
```

Please see the examples for more details, but here is a quick example: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/examples/mongocxx/query.cpp#L43

Lifetime management in the C++ driver requires attention. Please read the doc comments for the methods you use, as they will almost always describe the rules you must follow.

Comment: find_one does not return a cursor like find. It returns optional<value>

Comment: @kroiz - Fair enough, I didn't catch that it was `find_one` rather than `find`. But the point is still valid that they were viewing freed memory by retaining a `view` into a temporary `value`.

Comment: Sure, and I appreciate that and thus also I accepted as answer. Just mentioned this for future readers.